# addChild() duplicates MovieClip instead of removing from parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

When using `addChild()` with an object added to the stage in the .fla, the object remains as a child of its original parent (minus any additions made in AS), and the new parent contains a copy of the object (with any additions made in AS). The same thing happens when using `removeChild()` or adding to the same parent.

How can I stop it from leaving the duplicate?

Comment: You have probably done something very weird. Please provide your code for relevant parts and explain what it is you are trying to do and what you expect it to do.

Comment: It sounds like you might actually be adding the original object twice.

Comment: apparently an extra frame was added that caused this

Comment: We need some code. Doing another `addChild()` sets your MC's parent to new one, and drops the old parent's displaylist link.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: He already answered - extra frame - it could be as with each frame it could instantiate new object leaving old objects on stage.